# What does 会えたらいいです mean

Tags: grammar

I get that 会え is to meet and いい is good but a bit confused on the たら part? Looked it up and it's like a conditional formatting for a verb?

So would the sentence translate to something like, it would be good to meet you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

たら being "conditional" means that it imparts a sense of "if X then Y".

So: 会**える** = **can** meet, たら = if/then, いい = good,

> 会えたらいいです = "If we can meet, then it'd be good."

Or more naturally in English:

> **"It'd be good if we could meet."**
>   or **"I hope we can meet."**
>   or **"I hope I can see you." / "I'd like to meet you."**

(depending on context, one of these might feel more natural than the others, for example, a business setting vs. a friend get-together vs. a date)

Comment: though I should point out that the Japanese 会えたらいいです is casual, so best not to use it in a formal business conversation or message, really.